# Count number of occurrences based on user id

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports, sugarcrm

I'm very new to SQL/MySQL and Stackoverflow for that matter, and I'm trying to create a query through *iReport* (though I don't have to use *iReport*) for *SugarCRM CE*. What I need is to create a report that displays the number of "Referrals", "Voicemails", "Emails", and "Call_ins" that are linked to a specific "user" (employee). The query I currently have set up works; however it is running through the data multiple times generating a report that is 200+ pages. This is the code that I am currently using:

```
SELECT
 ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `leads` INNER JOIN `leads_cstm` ON `leads`.`id` = `leads_cstm`.`id_c` WHERE (leadtype_c = 'Referral' AND users.`id` = leads.`assigned_user_id`) ),
 ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `leads` INNER JOIN `leads_cstm` ON `leads`.`id` = `leads_cstm`.`id_c` WHERE (leadtype_c = 'VM' AND users.`id` = leads.`assigned_user_id`) ),
 ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `leads` INNER JOIN `leads_cstm` ON `leads`.`id` = `leads_cstm`.`id_c` WHERE (leadtype_c = 'Email' AND users.`id` = leads.`assigned_user_id`) ),
 users.`first_name`,users.`last_name`
FROM
 `users` users,
 `leads` leads
```

I would appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use conditional summation.  The following uses MySQL syntax:

```
SELECT sum(leadtype_c = 'Referral') as Referrals,
       sum(leadtype_c = 'VM') as VMs,
       sum(leadtype_c = 'Email') as Emails,
       users.`first_name`, users.`last_name`
FROM users join
    `leads`
     on  users.`id` = leads.`assigned_user_id` INNER JOIN
     `leads_cstm`
     ON `leads`.`id` = `leads_cstm`.`id_c`
group by users.id;
```

Comment: You FAST)  sum(CASE WHEN leadtype_c = 'Referral' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) I want to added in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT` with `CASE` for this:

```
SELECT u.first_name, 
    u.last_name, 
    count(case when leadtype_c = 'Referral' then 1 end),
    count(case when leadtype_c = 'VM' then 1 end),
    count(case when leadtype_c = 'Email' then 1 end)
FROM users u
    JOIN leads l ON u.id = l.assigned_user_id
    JOIN leads_cstm lc ON l.id = lc.id_c
GROUP BY u.id
```

To match your exact results, you should probably use an `OUTER JOIN` instead, but this gives you the idea.

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: @user2636343 -- np, glad we could help!